# How to trigger a mongoose updatedAt

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to update my model when the data has changed. Sadly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403543/how-do-i-set-the-updatedat-timestamp-using-mongoose-during-a-data-migration) seems to not work.

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const moment = require('moment');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SomeSchema = new Schema({
  query: String,
  data: Object,
  userId: String,
  // Date.now() does work. I'm working with existing code.
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: moment().format() },
  updatedAt: { type: Date, default: moment().format() }
});

// Not sure why I need this 
// Have also used 'save' instead of 'updateOne'
SomeSchema.pre('updateOne', function(next) {
    this.updated = Date.now();
    // this.updatedAt = Date.now() does not work either.
    return next();
});

mongoose.model('someModel', SomeSchema);
```

Actual usage:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Model = mongoose.model('someModel');

// Ideally, I wanted something like "Model.findOrCreate" but... cant see that

const obj = {..};

// Im happy nothing will error here with this.
// Would love to use "findOrCreate" instead.
const data = await Model.updateOne({ ...obj });

// I hate this so much... by hey.
if (data.n === 0) {
  // Create
  Model.create({...obj}).save
}
```

All Im saying is, if the data is there, update it and if not, create it. But my `updatedAt` key is not updating at all. It stays the same as the `createdAt`. Based on the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps), I dont see how I'd use `$set` here.

The main thing is to trigger `updatedAt` **whenever** the data was found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script example using [*MongoDB Atlas Triggers*](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/triggers/database-triggers):

```js
exports = function(changeEvent) {
  const { updateDescription, fullDocument, ns } = changeEvent;
  const updatedFields = Object.keys(updateDescription.updatedFields);
  
  // For debug
  //console.log('changeEvent', JSON.stringify(changeEvent));

  const isUpdated = updatedFields.some(field =>
    field.match(/updatedAt/)
  );
  const updatedAt = fullDocument.updatedAt;

  // Prevent update again after the update
  if (!isUpdated || !updatedAt) {
    const { _id } = fullDocument;
    
    console.log(`Triggered! ${ns.db}:${ns.coll}:${_id}, isUpdated:${isUpdated ? 'true' : 'false'}, updatedAt:${updatedAt}`);
    
    const mongodb = context.services.get(ns.db /* Cluster Name, like the DB name */);
    const collection = mongodb.db(ns.db).collection(ns.coll);
    
    collection.updateOne({
      _id: _id,
    }, {
      $set: {
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a typo in the `Pre` middleware function. Based on our Schema the key name is `updatedAt`, but in the function, it's mentioned as `updated`.

Comment: Hi. Yes. I've also tried `this.updatedAt` but still the same.